# Flutter RIverpod changing state strangely

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, riverpod-generator

I have to state providers. The second one (listWithGlobalIDProvider) depends on the first one (currentListProvider) but the first one is independent. But Adding value to the second provider changes the first provider's value. I am calling the listWithGlobalIDProvider inside a futterProvider.

```dart
final currentListProvider =
    StateProvider.autoDispose<BracketList>((ref) {
  final brackets = ref.watch(_currentUserBracketListFutureProvider).value;
  ref.keepAlive();
  return brackets ?? [];
});

final listWithGlobalIDProvider =
    StateProvider.autoDispose<BracketList>((ref) {
  final brackets = ref.watch(currentListProvider);
  final List<String> list = brackets;
  list.add(GlobalBracketID.globalBrackerID);
  ref.keepAlive();
  return list;
});
```

```yaml
flutter_riverpod: ^2.2.0
```

I am expecting that calling the second stateProvider not change the first provider value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you could change the line

```
final List<String> list = brackets;
```

to instead be

```
final List<String> list = List<String>.from(brackets);
```

This should ensure that modifying the second provider won't change the first provider.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But did not understand what is happing here?  Can you explain?

Comment: In your version of the code, we are not making a new list.  We are just setting the `list` variable to point to the existing brackets (which is set to watch currentListProvider in the previous line).  In contrast, my version makes a NEW list based on brackets (using the `from` constructor of the `List` class). In other words, `final List<String> list = brackets;` assigns a reference to the original list, whereas `final List<String> list = List<String>.from(brackets);` creates a new list with the same elements as the original list.